# How to Open specific file in specific folder with macro excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How to Open specific file in specific folder with macro excel. 
Example I put Path in cell A1 "D:\My Data", and I put sub directory in A2 "Kitchen"
and last I put file name in A3 "Rack.xls"

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

This will open an excel workbook -

```
Sub arfan()
Dim myfile As String

myfile = Cells(1, 1).Value & Cells(1, 2).Value & Cells(1, 3).Value

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```

But, this requires A1 to end with `\` and A2 to end with `\` and A3 to have the correct file extension

If that's not the case, just change *myfile* to `myfile = Cells(1, 1).Value & "\" & Cells(1, 2).Value & "\" & Cells(1, 3).Value`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified example that allows you to use several cell references from the active row.  In my spreadsheet the files are named with underscores between the cell values, so you will see those in between some of the cell references.  This works when you are selected on any cell in the row.

```
Sub OpenXLSM()
Dim myfile As String

myfile = "C:\Folder\Folder\" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) & "\" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11) & "_" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 12) & "_" &  Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) & "*.xlsm"

Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```